# I am proposing two conjectures regarding the BCH codes ! Can anybody prove or disprove my conjectures?

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, coding-theory, galois-extensions, reed-muller-codes

I was working with BCH codes for Compressed Sensing. Through the simulation of BCH codes, I found some interesting facts which are useful for my Ph.D. thesis. I don't have mathematical proof of my findings regarding the BCH codes. Therefore I am proposing two conjectures. I want to see if anyone of you can prove or disprove my conjecture regarding the BCH codes. Now I begin stating my conjectures.

**Conjecture 1 :**
For every integer $m\geq 3$,

(1) **if $m$ is even**, then there exists a BCH code of block length $2^m -1$, with minimum distance $2^{m-1}- 2^{\frac{m}{2}- 1}$, and the weight of codewords will be $0,\ 2^{m-1}-2^{\frac{m}{2} - 1},\ 2^{m -1},\ 2^{m - 1} + 2^{\frac{m}{2} - 1}$.

(2) **If $m$ is odd**, then there exists a BCH code of block length $2^{m}-1$, with minimum distance $2^{m-1}-2^{\frac{m+1}{2} - 1}$, and the weight of the codewords will be $0,\ 2^{m-1}-2^{\frac{m+1}{2} -1},\ 2^{m-1},\ 2^{m-1} + 2^{\frac{m+1}{2} - 1}$.

**Conjecture 2:**
For every integer $m\geq 4$,

(1) **if $m$ is even**, then there exists a BCH code of block length $2^{m}-1$, with minimum distance $2^{m-1} - 2^{\frac{m}{2}}$, and the weight of the codewords will be $0,\ 2^{m-1}- 2^{\frac{m}{2}},\ 2^{m-1}- 2^{\frac{m}{2}} + 2^{\frac{m}{2} - 1},\ 2^{m-1},\ 2^{m-1} + 2^{\frac{m}{2} - 1},\ 2^{m-1}+ 2^{\frac{m}{2}}$.

(2) **If $m$ is odd**, then there exists a BCH code of block length $2^{m}-1$, with minimum distance $2^{m-1} - 2^{\frac{m+1}{2}}$, and the weight of the codewords will be $0,\ 2^{m-1}- 2^{\frac{m+1}{2}},\ 2^{m-1}- 2^{\frac{m+1}{2}} + 2^{\frac{m+1}{2} - 1},\ 2^{m-1},\ 2^{m-1} + 2^{\frac{m+1}{2} - 1},\ 2^{m-1}+ 2^{\frac{m+1}{2}}$.

I am proposing these two conjectures based on my simulation results. In simulations, I have verified these two conjectures for $m = 3$ to $20$. These two conjectures are so important to my Ph.D. thesis, and I will get one more research paper based on these two conjectures.
Please let me know if you know any mathematical proof of my conjectures. I would be very grateful to you.

**Obligatory disclosure:** I am pursuing a Ph.D. in Electrical Engineering. My thesis work is on Compressed Sensing. I am using the BCH codes to design a Measurement Matrix for compressed sensing.

Comment: I am not sure these are conjectures! In particular, @JyrkiLahtonen already pointed out the Gold (there are other equivalent sequence constructions in terms of Hamming Distance) construction which obeys one (or more) of these cases in an earlier version of your question.

Comment: @kodlu ; Do you mean that they don't qualify to be a conjecture?

Comment: Have look at the reference. I think your conjectures are corollaries of known results.

Comment: So, you can probably obtain what you want directly from the references in my now updated answer.

Comment: I think you should also mention the name Tadeo Kasami. See the references in [Dilip Sarwate's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4597891/11619) recent answer to your question. Proving these properties is not difficult, if you are at all familiar with character sums over finite fields. I should be able to reproduce a proof on demand, because a significant chunk of my research from late 1990s relied on that technique.

Comment: Oh, Kodlu (+1) also mentioned Kasami. Anyway, I'm glad to hear your application no longer demands codes that do not exist.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; If you can produce the proof of my conjecture, it would be a great help.

Comment: The proof for the case $m=2k$ is actually (more or less verbatim) [on the site already](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3498683/11619). You do need to replace the constant $256$ appearing there with $2^{2m}$, and the two trace functions should be $tr_k$ and $tr_m$ instead of $tr_4$ and $tr_8$. I can write it in the general case, but need to do something else first. Mean while do check that out, to see if you know the machinery. Dilip Sarwate knows more about the history of these results, and could do the honors.

Comment: I'm sure you can find Kasami's original papers from *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory* (or its relevant predecessor).

Comment: Oh, and you also need to replace the exponent $17$ with $2^k+1$.  That proof there is for the case $k=4$, but it goes thru for any $k$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; Thank you very much! I will try to understand those papers as much as I can. However, if you can me give direct proof, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

See for example the paper Boztas and Kumar, Binary Sequences with Gold-like Correlation but Larger Linear Span, [IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 40.2 (1994), 532-537](https://doi.org/10.1109/18.312181), full-text available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3078434_Binary_sequences_with_Gold-like_correlation_but_larger_linear_span).

The sequence family is simply the BCH code with only one codeword taken from each cyclic equivalence class.

Theorem 1 proves the case for $m$ odd. The authors did not bother proving $m$ even, since in that case the solution is not optimal with respect to the Welch bound.

By the way, one should just state case 1 for $m=3$ separately, the second conjecture is really the same as the first other than $m=3.$

An earlier related reference is the University of Illinois report by T. Kasami from 1966 available  [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/158319552.pdf).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen feel free to edit my answer. I can make it community wiki if you wish.

Comment: @DilipSarwate feel free to edit my answer. I can make it community wiki if you wish.

Comment: No need for that in my opinion. This answer serves well.